# Store a php statement parameter in a variable

Tags: php

The following statement successfully queries a database and sets the `IdPhoto` field to the `$IdPhoto` variable among other things.

```
$result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);
```

How can one do the same with the `IdUser` field? Would this statement be correct?

**Update**

```
$result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE l.IdUser='%d' AND p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto, $IdUser);
```

My ultimate goal is to set the hypothetical $IdUser field to a global so it has to be precise.

Comment: Thank you. Can you verify whether or not the update's syntax is correct? I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it part of the WHERE clause, you can't put it in after you've started the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    $IdPhoto = $row['IdPhoto'];
    $IdUser= $row['IdUser'];
}
```